# Get id of a button with request.getParam

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have multiple buttons with same name but different values.

```
<input type="submit" id="1" value="1" name="disksheet" onclick="getId(this.id)"/>

<input type="submit" id="2" value="2" name="disksheet" onclick="getId(this.id)"/>

<input type="submit" id="3" value="3" name="disksheet" onclick="getId(this.id)"/>
```

On button click, I am trying to get the value of the button and find out which one of the button was clicked. I am trying to do this using a `request.getParameter("disksheet")` in my JSP page.

```
function getId(diskid) {
    var form = document.getElementById("form"); 
    var id = diskid;

    var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater("output",
            "/jsp/Limiter.jsp", {
                asynchronous : true,
                postBody : Form.serialize(form), id,
                data: diskid,
                method : 'post',

                onComplete : function() {

            }

            });

}
```

Limiter.jsp Page:

```
<% String id = request.getParameter("disksheet")%>
```

However, this just returns the value of the first button which is 1 every time no matter what button I click. I want to get the value through a single request so that i don't have to write multiple if else statements for rest of the page.

Comment: @Frakcool Yes i know. My question was how do i call this Jsp from Java. Since i have both in my codes, i tried to tag both.

Comment: Then clarify your question as it's confusing and since you only showed javascript code, I thought it was a JS only question

Comment: @Frakcool K. I will try to elaborate it. I did mention request.getParam in my question and answer both.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you are giving the same name to the three buttons?

Comment: How is the input submitted? Is it via normal html form or you have some javascript doing the magic?

Comment: @Jayr I am submitting it to my JSP page through an AJAX call. I updated my codes

Comment: I believe the source code you shared is not properly formatted. However it seems that whats happening in your case is described here: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/serializeElements/ where in the option section, its saying "submit (Boolean | String): In essence: If you omit this option the first submit button in the form is included;" Can help update your question the html section that shows how the form tag is enclosing the input.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting the wrong parameter name. You are sending diskid in your Ajax but requesting disksheet.

This is working for me with a servlet called Test:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" id="1" value="1" name="disksheet"
        onclick="getId(this.id)" />
    <input type="submit" id="2" value="2" 
        name="disksheet" onclick="getId(this.id)" />
    <input type="submit"
        id="3" value="3" name="disksheet" onclick="getId(this.id)" />
    <h2 id="output"></h2>
<script>     
 function getId(id){
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : 'test',
            data : {
                diskid : id
            },
            success : function(responseText) {
                console.log("from servlet ", responseText);
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = responseText;
            }
        });      
    }       
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And as a servlet I have:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String clickedButton = request.getParameter("diskid");
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().write("clicked " + clickedButton);
}
```

An output example:

[image: Output example]

Comment: That does not return null. Maybe you are doing something else, somewhere else. I added an image with the output example I am getting with the console.log and a <h2> receiving the clicked id.